# Want large first page header, rest of document with smaller header

Tags: header-footer

Attempting to add a header and footer to the IEEEtran conference paper (the 2 column one).  At present I'm able to get the footer that I want on all the pages, as my conference requires me to.

However I'm trying to get 3 lines on the first page header.  This seems to "squish" the footers on all the pages.  I believe that if I change the margin geometries, this will apply to all the pages, but I only want a large header for the first page and the rest to have standard (not large) margins.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation labelling
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption} % make captions smaller text and make them BOLD 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{enumerate} % to create fancy enumerated lists
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for headers on each page (and customization of them)
\usepackage{float} % for allowing "floating" of figures
% \usepackage[top=1 in, bottom=1 in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry} % edit individual margins
\usepackage{graphicx} % for figures in general
\usepackage{hyperref} % for "clickable" links to figures/refs/(etc.)
\usepackage{lastpage} % for page __ of __
\usepackage{multicol} % for multiple column environments (mostly used with equations)
\usepackage{mdwlist}  % tighter packed bulleted lists
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} % for getting rid of extra space in references section 
\usepackage{setspace} % for line spacing between lines and also for bibliography
\usepackage{siunitx} % for scientific units (add [scientific-notation=true] for scientific notation always)
\usepackage{tabularx} % to try and get variable-spacing columns




\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}


% ####################### Header and Footer Stuff
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
{
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Copyright \textcopyright \vspace{1em} 2018}
}
%
\fancypagestyle{firstpage} %{style}
{
    \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{line 1 \\
        line2 \\
        line3}}
}




\graphicspath{{./img/}}


\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor = black,
    linkcolor = blue, % link colour for figure, equation, + table refs
    urlcolor = blue, 
}




\begin{document}


\title{\Large\textbf{title title title}}


\author
{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{author}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{some place} \\
    %\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    stuff \\
    stuff2}

    \and

    \IEEEauthorblockN{author}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{some place} \\
    %\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    stuff \\
    stuff2}
}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\begin{abstract}
    \normalfont
    To be written
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    %\normalfont
    \textit{keyword1; keyword2; keyword3}
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\section{Introduction}

main body here



\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide small but complete document, that we can test your/ours ideas how to accomplish this ... help us to help you :-). welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Added more of document.  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** to code are added comments for clarifying meaning of code

a solution can be

```
...
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
...
```

complete minimal working example without special bothering with the article space issues and without complete header/footer formatting:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\addtolength\headheight{ 2\baselineskip}% make space for your multi line header
\addtolength\headheight{-2\baselineskip}% you need to reduce text height 
                                                                 % for the same amount as you increase 
                                                                 % header height

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for headers on each page (and customization of them)
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% change to your desired width (0pt?)
\pagestyle{fancy}
{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\cfoot{% here you can define font size in cfoot
  \thepage}
\rfoot{% here you can define font size in rfoot
    Copyright \textcopyright\ 2018}% corrected your code
\rhead{\bfseries\footnotesize % <--- here is defined font size in rhead
    line 1 \\
    line 2 \\
    line 3}
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Copyright \textcopyright\ 2018}% corrected your code
\rhead{\bfseries\color{red}\large
    line 1 \\
    line 2 \\
    line 3}
}

\title{\Large\textbf{title title title}}
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{author}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{some place} \\
    %\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    stuff \\
    stuff2}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{author}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{some place} \\
    %\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    stuff \\
    stuff2}
        }

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\begin{abstract}
    \normalfont
    To be written
\end{abstract}

%\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    %\normalfont
%    \textit{keyword1; keyword2; keyword3}
%\end{IEEEkeywords}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

the first page:

[image]

and others pages:

[image]

**addendum:**
your observation in comment is not accurate. see, what you will obtained using the following definition of `fancy` and `firstpage` page styles definition:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Copyright \textcopyright \vspace{1em} 2018}
\rhead{\bfseries\tiny
    line 1 \\
    line 2 \\
    line 3}
}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Copyright \textcopyright \vspace{1em} 2018}
\rhead{\bfseries\color{red}\Huge
    line 1 \\
    line 2 \\
    line 3}
}
```

hopefully now difference (with this extreme difference of font sizes) is clearly evident :-)

**note:** desire font size is left to you. my intention was only to show a way (method) how to solve your problem. all details of header design i left to you. so you should change color, rule, font size and other content of headers as you like to have.

Comment: This header looks to be the same size on both the first page and all other pages. Is this the case?

Comment: no, it is not the case. and they are different size (`large` and `footnotesize`), even more, larger is emphasized in red color :-) (both images have the same size)

Comment: Thank you for your continued help :).  Unfortunately this still has the issue of "squishing" the footer. See image: https://imagebin.ca/v/3ra9Tk8YLT9k

Comment: @bsquared, but your question is about header only. the footer i left as you define it. if you like to change font size in footers too, than do this on the same way as i done for headers.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how to edit the header without touching the footer height. It seems that the footer height keeps getting affected as the header height is changed.  Maybe a textbox could be used instead (less desirable but I'll use it if I have to)

Comment: @bsquared, no. they have `\normalsize` font size. please, make some experiments with font size as i explain in the previous comment. for example as `\rfoot{\tiny Copyright \textcopyright\ 2018}`. if this work for you, change font size to your wish.

Comment: Regarding "squished" footer, try this: For the special page style, use `\smash{}` as a wrapper for the footer text and page number. That gives it the magical ability to change size, without moving the baseline. Note that `\smash{}` cannot be used when text wraps, as the smashed text is in a box.

Comment: @bsquared, see edited answer.

Comment: Zarko -- havne't been able to see an effect with different text sizes...still squishes footer.

@RobtAll .. attempted to play around with smash a bit but same issue persists

Thank you both for helping as you did.  I used a textblock in the end as those 3 lines were only needed once.  As the question originally asked about the header, I'm marking the answer as accepted...

Comment: @bsquared, ask new question. for it prepare real small document, for example based on my answer, and show us, what you try and where you stuck. on this way more people will see your problem and will be able to help you, probably on better way as i do here.